# Nested resource form values missing after failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a simple scenario of a form for a nested resource that works correctly other than when the validation fails the form is rendered with empty fields. I wish to repopulate the fields with the values the user entered.

**Controller**

```
  def new
    @department = Department.find(params["department_id"])
  end

  def create
    @department = Department.find(params["department_id"])
    @discussion = @department.discussions.new(discussion_params)
    @discussion.user_id = current_user.id
    if @discussion.save
      redirect_to department_discussions_path(@department)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def discussion_params
      params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :content)
    end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for([@department, @department.discussions.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control", rows: 5 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Model**

```
class Discussion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :department

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 25 }
end
```

**Routes**

```
  resources  :departments do
    resources :discussions  
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is the `Discussion` controller, try adding to `permit` the Department's parameters.

Maybe you can see the console some message like `Unpermitted parameters: var1 , var2`

Basically is some like this:

```
def discussion_params
    params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :content , departments_attributes: [ :var1, :var2 ])
end
```